# PROJECT error in terra. "Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function project for signature character"

Tags: raster, r, terra

I'm trying to change the projection of UTM rasters that look like this:

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 36828, 45995, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent      : 433390, 893340, 6039570, 6407850  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N (EPSG:25832) 
source      : landcover_ext_agri_2011.tif 
name        : C_01 
min value   :    0 
max value   :    1
```

By using a subset of rasterstacks (LON/LAT) that look like this:

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 4800, 6720, 19  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)  
extent      : -14.00014, 41.99986, 34.99986, 74.99986  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)
```

```
regexp <- "[[:digit:]]+"
patt <- "landcover_([A-Za-z_]+(?:_[A-Za-z]+)*)(_\\d{4})" 

for(file in allfiles){ 
  lu = rast(file.path(luDir,file))
  yearOf = str_extract(file, regexp)
  typelulc = str_match(file, patt)
  lulonlat <- terra::project(file, crs(ch1), method="near")  
  writeRaster(lulonlat, filename=file.path(luOut,paste0('landcover_', typelulc,'_',yearOf, '_lonlat', '.tif')),filetype="GTiff", datatype="INT1U", gdal=c("COMPRESS=DEFLATE","TFW=NO"))
 
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
            unable to find an inherited method for function ‘project’ for signature ‘"character"’
```

Comment: Changed the `rstudio` tag to `r` because its not a question about `rstudio`, but about `r` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point:

```
lulonlat <- terra::project(file, crs(ch1), method="near")
```

`file` is the name of the file, not the R raster data object read in. That's what the error is telling you:

```
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘project’ for signature ‘"character"’
```

It can't work out how to do `project("/path/to/file.tif")`. You need to project the object you get when reading the data into R.

You already do this at:

```
lu = rast(file.path(luDir,file))
```

So I think the solution is to project `lu`, via:

```
lulonlat <- terra::project(lu, crs(ch1), method="near")
```

all other things being correct at that point.